# iPad Chrome HTML click select option, but display another option

Tags: html, ipad, google-chrome, html-select

In PC Chrome & IE, it works. But in iPAD Chrome, when I select month or year, it display the option of day. And the code related as below.

```
<td class="label" nowrap="nowrap"><label for="InputLabel2">Fax Received Date To</label></td>
<td><label>
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="InputLabel2" VALUE="D/2014/10/22:17:19:28">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="InputLabel2_dirtyFlag" VALUE="0">

<LABEL FOR="InputLabel2_day"></LABEL>
<SELECT ID="InputLabel2_day" TITLE="Day" NAME="InputLabel2_day" onChange="InputLabel2_update(this, this.form, null)">
<OPTION VALUE="-1" >
<OPTION VALUE="1" >1
<OPTION VALUE="22" SELECTED>22
<OPTION VALUE="31" >31
</SELECT>
&nbsp;---&nbsp;
<LABEL FOR="InputLabel2_month"></LABEL>
<SELECT ID="InputLabel2_month" TITLE="Month" NAME="InputLabel2_month" onChange="InputLabel2_update(this, this.form, null)">
<OPTION VALUE="-1" >
<OPTION VALUE="1" >January
<OPTION VALUE="10" SELECTED>October
<OPTION VALUE="12" >December
</SELECT>
&nbsp;---&nbsp;
<LABEL FOR="InputLabel2_year"></LABEL>
<SELECT ID="InputLabel2_year" TITLE="Year" NAME="InputLabel2_year" onChange="InputLabel2_update(this, this.form, null)">
<OPTION VALUE="-1" >
<OPTION VALUE="2013" >2013
<OPTION VALUE="2014" SELECTED>2014
<OPTION VALUE="2015" >2015
</SELECT>
```

Comment: why option not closed it should be <option value="1">1</option>

Answer (score 0):

find the issue, it is due to , it should not have the additional  after , and once remove it, it works in iPad Chrome now. Thx all